# connection with sql command

Tags: php, mysql

How do I execute a command as and when a new mysql connection is established from php?

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gts");
```

In the above exmaple, I need to pass set sql command :

```
sql_log_bin = 0
```

This will make sure that the commands executed by this connection will not be written to binary log. I have another "normal" connection that will work as usual and write all the commands to binary log.

In other words I need 2 connections to mysql one with disabled binary logging. I should be able to decide which one to use. How is it done in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need two connections with different parameters, just establish two connections:

```
$con1 = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gts");
$con2 = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gts");
```

Then have a look at `mysqli_options` function:

```
bool mysqli_options ( mysqli $link , int $option , mixed $value );
```

In your case, it'll be something like

```
mysqli_options ( $con1 , MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND , "SET sql_log_bin = 0" );
```

to turn this binary log off on connection 1.

Finally, when you need to run any queries, use `$con1` if you do not need binary logging and `$con2` if you do.

Answer (score 2):

First create two connections.

```
$con1=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gts");
$con2=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gts");
```

Then on one of them disable your binlog

```
mysqli_query($con1, "SET sql_log_bin = 0");
```